# wpf listbox checkbox change color when checked or selected

Tags: wpf, checkbox, listbox, selecteditem, listitem

I have tried the different examples on this site to get the list box / check box combo to change from the default gray when selected to another color to no avail.

What I am trying to do in the end is if the item is checked, the background will be white, and when unchecked it will gray out.

Here is what I have and any help would be appreciated.

Update the resource to the comment below.

The control has been updated to the reply and still not working, any ideas?

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            Name="lstSwimLane" SelectionMode="Multiple"
            Width="auto" 
            Height="auto"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0" 
            SelectionChanged="LstSwimLaneSelectionChanged">

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource UnselectedBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                    
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,3,3,3">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                                Checked="ChkFilterChecked" 
                                Unchecked="ChkFilterUnchecked" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Margin="0,0,4,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Note: The checked checkboxes and list item combination is still gray and the unchecked is white.

Attached is a screen shot which seems to match the reply have below.  I am stumped.

[image: screen shot]

Here is the direct link in order to see the image bigger.
http://s1120.photobucket.com/albums/l489/nitefrog/?action=view&current=jw_0012011-03-311325.jpg

Here is the screen shot of the checkboxes.

[image]

http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l489/nitefrog/jw_0022011-03-311345.jpg

Even though the brushes are set, for some reason they are not being triggered.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My example doesn't use the `myListboxStyle` style, you can remove it. But change the `ItemContainerStyle` property:

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBrush}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource UnselectedBrush}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

It is very simple template and it has only two triggers: `IsSelected=True` and `IsSelected=False`.
And to complete this example add these brushes to the `Resources` collection:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBrush" Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="UnselectedBrush" Color="Gray"/>
```

It would be better to edit the standard style for the `ListViewItem`, but I can't find it in the internet and I don't have Expression Blend now.

Screen of the result:
[image]

Comment: Does not work.  Everything selected is still gray and everything unselected is white.  I cut and pasted the code above.

Comment: @nitefrog Compare your current code with the screenshot above. In my application the checked state is white, unchecked is gray, everything as you need.

Comment: @nitefrog It's strange, but the code from your question has the same result: unchecked gray and checked white. Probably the problem is in the two brushes in the `Resources` element.

Comment: @vortex I just uploaded two screen shots to show you.  I am completely at a loss on this one.

Comment: @nitefrog Brushes are not triggered, probably I know where the problem is. Try to remove the line with event handler `SelectionChanged="LstSwimLaneSelectionChanged"`. It seems to me that you change the `IsSelected` property of `ListBoxItem` somewhere in code-behind.

Comment: @vortex The only thing is that I need to reload a tree control whenever a box is unselected.

Comment: @nitefrog Where is the tree control? I wasn't warned about additional parts. Anyway the problem is 100% somewhere in the code-behind, because there is no difference in xaml between your code and mine.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I will dig in.  The tree is the left side of the screen.  It is refreshed when the options are changed.